# How to create 3 panels of the same size

Tags: java, swing

i'm having issues creating 3 equal sized panels with the North panel being a display and the south panel being a display. The Middle panel is split into 2 sections East and West with the West being a textbox that the user can enter String into and the East being the start button. How can i fix my Center panel so that it is equal size with my north and south panels?

What my application looks like:

[image]

correct example of application:

[image]

Code:

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class ThreadedFillDemo2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener,
        Runnable {
    public static final int WIDTH = 300;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 200;
    public static final int FILL_WIDTH = 300;
    public static final int FILL_HEIGHT = 100;
    public static final int CIRCLE_SIZE = 10;
    public static final int PAUSE = 100; // milliseconds

    private JPanel northBox;
    private JPanel southBox;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadedFillDemo2 gui = new ThreadedFillDemo2();
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }

    public ThreadedFillDemo2() {
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setTitle("Location Finder");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));

        northBox = new JPanel();
        southBox = new JPanel();
        add(northBox);

        JTextField entry = new JTextField();
        JLabel entryTitle = new JLabel("Enter Postal Code"); 


        JButton startButton = new JButton("Get Location");
        startButton.addActionListener(this);



        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel buttonPaneleast = new JPanel();
        JPanel buttonPanelwest = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        buttonPanelwest.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        buttonPaneleast.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        buttonPanelwest.add(entryTitle);
        buttonPanelwest.add(entry);
        buttonPaneleast.add(startButton);



        buttonPanel.add(buttonPanelwest);
        buttonPanel.add(buttonPaneleast);
        add(buttonPanel);
        add(southBox);






    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        startThread();
    }

    synchronized public void run() {
        Graphics g =northBox.getGraphics();
        for (int y = 0; y < FILL_HEIGHT; y = y + CIRCLE_SIZE)
            for (int x = 0; x < FILL_WIDTH; x = x + CIRCLE_SIZE) {
                g.fillOval(x, y, CIRCLE_SIZE, CIRCLE_SIZE);
                doNothing(PAUSE);
            }
    }

    synchronized public void startThread() {
        Thread theThread = new Thread(this);
        theThread.start();
    }

    synchronized public void doNothing(int milliseconds) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Unexpected interrupt");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, a `GridLayout(3, 1)` for the `contentPane` would just do fine. (I wouldn't mess arround with the `preferredSize`s of the panels)

Comment: Wouldn't that just create 3 grid blocks on top of another? I need a North Panel, South Panel, and Center Panel that is split into a grid of (1,2) with the west center panel being the textField, and the East center Panel being the start button. Problem happens when i try and make them all the same size.

Comment: Then `GridLayout(1, 2)`, with a nested `GridLayout(2, 1)` on the left and `GridLayout()` on the right.

Comment: @stacker *"Wouldn't that just create 3 grid blocks on top of another"* - Isn't that exactly what you want? It would produce the same UI as your example image. Or is it for some odd reason a requirement to use `BorderLayout()`? If yes, you could override the `getPreferredSize()` of each panel (with `return new Dimension(getParent().getWidth(), getParent().getHeight() / 3)`, for example). But I wouldn't recommend it if you can use `GridLayout`.

Comment: Alright so that worked! Now i just need to figure out how to get that black boarder line around the center panel. Any ideas?

Comment: @stacker `centerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));` (probably also do that with the north & south panel)

Comment: Really appreciate the help, thanks a million!